# Upgrade opencart 2.0.3.1 to 2.2.0.0 error

Tags: opencart2.x

I want to upgrade my opencart version from 2.0.3.1 to 2.2.0.0 (latest version). I upgrade according http://docs.opencart.com/upgrading/.

But I get an error on `www.mystore.com/install`.

Error notification:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

[image: screenshot]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I got past this error by truncating the customer_activity table in the database. it's just a table containing data about your customer activity, such as "Customer x logged in at y" - no crucial information..

Answer (score -1):

[OpenCart Migration & Upgrade Tool](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=19572)  will do your life easier.

It will help you to upgrade your store.